# When to use <span> instead <p>?

Tags: html

As the question indicates, if I have some text that I want to add in the HTML then when should I use `<p>` and when should I use `<span>`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You should keep in mind, that HTML is intended to DESCRIBE the content it contains.

So, if you wish to convey a paragraph, then do so.

Your comparison isn't exactly right, though. The more direct comparison would be

> When to use a `<div>` instead of a `<p>`?

as both are block level elements.

A `<span>` is inline, much like an anchor (`<a>`), `<strong>`, emphasis (`<em>`), etc., so bear in mind that by it's default nature in both html and in natural writing, that a paragraph will cause a break before and after itself, like a `<div>`.

Sometimes, when styling things — inline things — a `<span>` is great to give you something to "hook" the css to, but it is otherwise an empty tag devoid of semantic or stylistic meaning.

Comment: When comparing inline vs. block elements, be careful not to describe the visual aspects. As the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-p-element.html#the-p-element) says, a `p` may not necessarily be styled with surrounding line breaks, for example, it could be followed by an inline [pilcrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) symbol. The terms "inline" and "block" also mean nothing to blind users.
Rather, make the distinction between **flow content** and **phrasing content** (see [this link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html)).

Comment: Also, padding-left behaves differently on `p` than it does on `span`. On paragraph, padding affects every line (block of text), while on span it only affects the first line.

Comment: @chharvey I was always confused by the dual nature of the HTML definition, for me, elements are there for me to hook things to via css or javascript. For others it's about the information within it. Which is strange, people pride themselves in being able to write HTML but nobody ever says they can generate JPG's by hand on their resume. The two seem analogous, we're just lucky to be able to see the information in an HTML document.

Answer (score 106):

Semantically, you use `<p>` tags to indicate paragraphs. `<span>` is used to apply CSS style and/or class(es) to an arbitrary section of text and inline elements.

Answer (score 19):

The `<p>` tag is a `p`aragraph, and as such, it is a *block* element (as is, for instance, `h1` and `div`), whereas `span` is an inline element (as, for instance, `b` and `a`)

Block elements by default create some whitespace above and below themselves, and nothing can be aligned next to them, unless you set a `float` attribute to them.

Inline elements deal with spans of text inside a paragraph. They typically have no margins, and as such, you cannot, for instance, set a `width` to it.

Comment: yes, span has no margins and so, it is good as table cell (td) to have ability to use html markup

Answer (score 10):

Span is completely non-semantic. It has no meaning, and serves merely as an element for cosmetic effects.

Paragraphs have semantic meaning - they tell a machine (like a browser or a screen reader) that the content they encapsulate is a block of text, and has the same meaning as a paragraph of text in a book.

Comment: I wish the HTML docs just had your paragraph pasted in it.

Answer (score 7):

A span is an inline formatting element that does NOT have a line feed above or below.

A p is a block element that HAS an implied line feed above and below.

http://w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

Answer (score 6):

The p tag denotes a paragraph element. It has margins/padding applied to it. A span is an unstyled inline tag. An important difference is that p is a block element when span is inline, meaning that `<p>Hi</p><p>There</p>` would appear on different lines when `<span>Hi</span><span>There</span>` winds up side by side.

Answer (score 6):

`<span>` is an inline tag, a `<p>` is a block tag, used for paragraphs. Browsers will render a blank line below a paragraph, whereas `<span>`s will render on the same line.

Answer (score 5):

Semantically speaking, a p is a paragraph tag and should be used to format a paragraph of text. A span is an inline formatting change that isn't handled semantically.

Answer (score 5):

A practical explanation: By default, `<p> </p>` will add line breaks before and after the enclosed text (so it creates a paragraph). `<span>` does not do this, that is why it is called *inline*.

Answer (score 2):

When we are using normal text at that time we want `<p>` tag.when we are using normal text with some effects at that time we want `<span>` tag

Comment: You can style `<p>` tags, too. There's no need to use a `<span>` tag instead. The difference is something else entirely as other answers already explain.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation

p element is a block level, therefore, add padding and margin before and after the line/ text. But span is inline element and therefore does not add any padding and margin before and after the line. We actually use span element for styling purpose and it has not semantic meaning in HTML, however, the p element is block element and has semantic meaning in HTML.

Answer (score -2):

#### P tag is not your friend.

Briefly:

> **1. Aggressive correction**
> Browsers will forcefully alter your HTML when you put another p tag inside a p tag, even if it's just a temporary thing. They won't let you.

> **2. Zero superpower**
> P tags have absolutely no special abilities, apart from this intolerant behaviour. No, not better for screen readers; not better for semantics, not better for SEO - nothing like that. Those are just made-up benefits; imagine Google not being able to find text in your divs, or a screen reader standing perplexed in front of a document enclosed in a span.

> **3. Inconsistent look**
> Regarding spaces before/after, like margins and padding, P tags have different defaults across the universe, so the first thing you do is reset them properly. After you do, they're nothing but a div - again, with a little surprise for tourists.

Now this may sound weird because everyone keeps recommending the use of `p`. It's because long ago they imagined HTML as a nice, clean document with some markup, and they named the most common ones with a single letter: you will have bold, italic, underline, umm what else?, sure, links, paragraphs, then headings, etc, it was like building a Word document. We're way past that, it's the late 1900s. We know better today.

But some people like standards that rigorously enforce themselves.

You'll be surprised when you first try to add a `<p>` inside of a `<p>...</p>` block. The browser will literally (and immediately) tear your tag in two: closes the previous one and opens another. This magic trick caused lots of trouble for WYSIWYG editors, even today it does. Browsers are tolerant, peaceful and understanding, but not for this one thing. They come and kill. And the only valid reason is, *"yeah but why would you do such a thing in the first place"*. What a point.

When you use `<p>`, you're using something that differs from other well-known tags in only one trait: they won't let you get away with a specific move. That's it. Even if you wanted nothing wrong; even if you allowed your visitor to paste a document inside a content-editable and you were ready to reformat it in the next split second. No. You let this happen, your browser strikes immediately.

Believe me. You don't need this. Keep playing by the rules but do it voluntarily. Today you can even have a very semantic custom tag, one that never existed before, and use it for paragraphs to further emphasize their role in your document.

**TLDR: use `div` or `span`, they will just do the job.**

Comment: [Note. CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class" attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted meanings and author-defined classes may not.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).

Comment: True story. Semantic tags are fine. With some exceptions where they do something awfully non-semantic.

Answer (score -8):

```
p {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

No spacing will be around, it looks similar to span.

Comment: `float` causes the `<p>` tag to act as an `inline-block` element while `<span>` is an `inline` element

Comment: this was exactly what I have encountered, thank you gasyoun