# CSS - How to remove unwanted margin between elements?

Tags: html, css, margin

This seems to be a common problem but none of the solutions I found have worked for me.

### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="c/lasrs.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="i/header1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. 
               Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, 
               massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, 
               bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    min-width: 950px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
}

.header {
    width: 950px;
    height: 171px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #E3EEF9;
    position: relative;
}
```

I deliberately broke the image path and set a background colour for the `.header` div so that I could see if they were touching. This is what my page looks like:

[image: page example]

As you can see I've tried setting the padding and margins on both `divs` to 0.

***Why is there still a gap?***

Comment: You must `reset` your `CSS`.

Comment: it's called [collapsing-margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is due to the following:

> Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each `<p>` element. The margins can be modified with CSS (with the margin properties).

So try:

```
p {
     margin: 0px;
}
```

Note: *browsers add default styling on other elements too!* This can be both useful and annoying in different situations. There are three ways to go about this:

1. **Completely remove any default styles that the browsers might have**. This is accomplished by using a *Reset Stylesheet*. The most popular one is [**Eric Meyer’s CSS Reset**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). If you want to go all out and have a *completely clean start* in any browser, use Meyer's technique. This method is preferred over using the slow `*{ margin:0; padding:0; }` reset approach ([Read here why](https://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/))
2. **Normalize the stylesheet to your own defaults**. A large annoyance of webdesigners is that different browsers use different default styles. However, a *complete reset* comes with the time-consuming trouble of redefining the styles of all elements. Therefore, you can *normalize* all default styles of the browsers by using a predefined set of consistent and sensible default styles. The common approach is to use [**normalize.css**](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) for this (*Twitter*, *Github* and *SoundCloud* use this!)
3. **Adjust the defaults when necessary or consciously work around the defaults**. The most common way (not saying it's the best way) to work with the defaults is to *know* they exist and adjust them when necessary. Default styles are there for a reason: they can help developers to quickly get the looks they are after. Is the look slightly off? Simply adjust the styles accordingly. However, make sure you use the correct tags for the correct elements. For example, instead of removing the `<p>` margins for [inline texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908234/when-to-use-span-instead-p/1908239#1908239), you should use the `<span>` tag (no default `margin`)

That should help you understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know what's causing the problem I can find a solution that doesn't involve removing the margins from my <p> tags.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not that "browsers automatically add" something, it's just the default stylesheets that are built-in in the browsers, which usually have `p { margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; }` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#flow-content-0). And these default margins [collapse with their containers margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) according to the CSS spec.

Comment: @Jean-Paul, probably. But I suppose that "adding" means something that wasn't there before (e.g. browsers _add_ `html`, `body`, and `tbody` elements even if there are no such tags in the markup), but default CSS _is_ already there, and it's the reason why CSS Resets are needed at all...

Comment: Thank you! I knew that <p> tags had a default margin but I had no idea it could extend outside of the width/height of the parent div. I'd been stumped on this for an hour lol. +1

Comment: For future readers.  The "p" got all mine except one.      h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }   An "H2" got me!  But this answer got me 99% of the way there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your margins in the paragraphs are overflowing out of the div (this is normal) you can either set

```
p {
   margin: 0;
}
```

or apply overflow hidden to your divs

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

in your style

Comment: This may be fine for testing, but it's definitely not the best solution for production. Some elements like form controls look terrible with zero padding, but default other styles.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JKS3k/3/

CSS

```
p{
   margin:0;           
}
```

OR

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this**:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both divs are touching. The margin/padding of DIVs is always 0 by default, so your modifications have no effect.
The `<p>` however does have a margin, and as it is nested into the div it looks like the div has a padding.

```
p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

will fix this.

Comment: Not completely right. In some cases (including this one) margins of nested elements cause the parent element to be shifted itself, because of [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). So the margin between paragraphs becomes the real margin between `div`s containing them.

Comment: Thanks @IlyaStreltsyn, I was aware of the existing margin collapsing, but I was unaware of the extent of this horrible idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using some reset css, because all browsers come with some default styling link margins, paddings, line-heights, font-styling and you need to start from none-styling elements.

I recommend using Eric Meyer reset CSS ( http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ )