# in JavaScript how do you stop JS overriding html?

Tags: javascript, html, function

not sure if the question is the best wording but here is my opportunity to simply explain.

i have this piece of html code

```
<p id="demoTemp"></p>
```

there is a function that uses the getElementById syntax and when i click a button, the function runs and the value is placed where the above html code is like so

-20

but what i want is simply this to print out

the value is -20

i tried this `<p> the value is <p id="demoTemp"></p> </p>` but it just printed it on different lines

Comment: use a `<span>` element, sinice it is by default inline, non boxed (p element are blocks)

Comment: Use spans instead of paragraphs if you want it on the same line

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use <span> instead <p>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908234/when-to-use-span-instead-p)

Comment: Why do you think that js overrides your html? Where is the js that you think is overriding your html?

Comment: sorted. solved. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p>` is block element use Inline element like `<span>`

> You cannot nest P elements inside P it is illegal. The P element represents a
>   paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P
>   itself). DIV however is a generic container where content can be
>   inline e.g SPAN or block-level. Hence DIV can contain P but not the
>   other-way around.

Try this:

```html
<p> the value is <span id="demoTemp">-20</span> </p>
```

Comment: i didnt? ive reticked it, not sure why it did that

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't nest `<p>` elements (or any block-level elements inside `<p>`) - the browser implicitly closes a paragraph before opening another block-level element, so

```
<p>something <p>nested</p> something</p>
```

Is interpreted by the browser as

```
<p>something </p>
<p>nested</p> 
something
<p></p>
```

You can only have inline-level elements inside a `<p>`, so use a span (or `<em>`, `<strong>` etc):

```
<p> the value is <span id="demoTemp"></span> </p>
```

The difference between block-level and inline-level elements is that the former create a line break (they try to occupy as much width as possible) while the latter shrink to wrap their contents.