# html5 semantics - span tag vs p tag

Tags: html

Is it semantically correct to use the span tag the way it's used in the following markup?

```
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

Should director and genre be placed inside of p elements? Should you replace the opening div with a p tag? It doesn't seem right to have director and genre just sitting inside of a span tag.

I'm learning html and came across this piece of code in the schema.org documentation. If someone could clarify things for me, I'd be really grateful. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use <span> instead <p>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908234/when-to-use-span-instead-p)

Comment: Not with a clear explanation

Comment: @user3907671 You can use this way but the `<span>` since it does not place any element of `block` within the `<span>`. `block` elements can not go inside elements `inline`. Correct me if I have said something wrong.

Comment: @user3907671 You want to read [the most voted answers first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908234/when-to-use-span-instead-p?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

As per the validator at http://validator.w3.org/check, this code conforms to HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Speaking about semantics, `span` tag "doesn't mean anything on its own, but can be useful when used together with the global attributes" (see [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element)). Using an attribute-free `span` tag is meaningless, and indeed, a `p` tag is what is recommended here.

Answer (score 1):

A `span` has no real semantic meaning by default in HTML. It's merely a way to block off inline content from other inline content.

A `div` doesn't have any real semantic meaning other. Both `div`s and `span`s are generic containers.

If you want to add *some* semantic meaning to your example, I'd suggest perhaps an unordered list or definition list.

All that said, is what you have incorrect? No, not necessarily--especially if the content, itself, is fairly self explanatory.